# Can't find the ASP.net ListView control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to extend the `ListView` control:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Resources;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Globalization;

namespace My.WebControls
{
  /// <summary>
  /// my ListView
  /// </summary>
  [Designer(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataBoundControlDesigner))]
  public class MyListView : ListView
  {
  }
}
```

But compiler does not see this control. I include the namespace `system.web.ui.webcontrols`. Do I have to check anything else? I use the framework 3.5.

Comment: Did you tried with inherit to `Controls` class?

Comment: Yes the `Control` class is found as well as `Datagrid` and other controls.

Comment: I think its problem of visual studio IDE. Try to clean and rebuild your solution, if not works then restart your machine.

Comment: using System.Collections.Generic - add this reference in your project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ListView` documentation [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.aspx) and you can see that the control exists in the **`System.Web.Extensions.dll`**

[image]

Re-check if you have this assembly in your references.

Here's the full namespaces of a working `MyList` class

```
[System.ComponentModel.Designer(typeof(System.Web.UI.Design.WebControls.DataBoundControlDesigner))]
public class MyCustomListView : System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView
{
    // ...
}
```

Because of the [`DataBoundControlDesigner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.design.webcontrols.databoundcontroldesigner.aspx) I also had to reference the **`System.Design.dll`**, verify if you also have such reference.

Comment: I forgot to reference the assembly.

Comment: How did you draw this red arrow?

Comment: I used the mouse ;) ... kidding: http://www.techsmith.com/download/jing/default.asp